# Fetch API works well on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, fetch

I have a Fetch API using openWeather API in my React.js APP , the fetch works fine on localhost but After I uploaded my code on GITHUB and deployed it on Heroku the app crashes when I use the button for the API request and gives this error :

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Not allowed to request resource
(anonymous function)**
src/App.js:89
  86 | const country=e.target.elements.country.value
  87 | 
  88 | if(city && country ){

> **89 |   const api_call=await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${Api_key}`)**
>        | ^  90 | const response=await api_call.json();
>     91 | this.setState({
>     92 |   city:`${response.name},${response.sys.country}`,

Any one can help me to fix this?

Comment: Where do you get the API key from on Heroku?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean? the key is embedded in my code as const and it works well on my localhost after I deployed on Heroku it shows this error